# Twisted spin-bordism invariant and a possible Postnikov square from $d=2$ to $d=5$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, homological-algebra, cobordism

This is a follow up more advanced question following [Twisted spin bordism invariants in 5 dimensions](https://mathoverflow.net/q/323078/27004). We follow the definitions in the [earlier post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/323078/27004).

I had discussed my computation of

$$
\Omega_5^{Spin \times_{\mathbb Z_2} \mathbb Z_{8}}= \mathbb Z_{32} \times \mathbb Z_{2},
$$

> **My specific question** is how to pin down the $\mathbb Z_{32}$ generator as a topological invariant? (like characteristic class or eta invariant).

---

> **My current proposal** is that the $\mathbb Z_{32}$
>   whether 1/2 of the $\mathbb Z_{32}$ is just the Postnikov square of 
>   $b \in H^2(B \mathbb Z_8, \mathbb Z_8)$.
>
> $$\text{Postnikov  square from $b \in H^2(B \mathbb Z_8, \mathbb Z_8)$ to $H^5(B \mathbb Z_8, \mathbb Z_{16})$}$$
>
> Can this be proved or disproved, so falsified?

Let $X$ is any $\mathbb Z_{32}$ topological term in the dimension $d=5$,

then 
consider $X'$ be the pullback of $X$ from
$\Omega_5^{Spin \times_{\mathbb Z_2} \mathbb Z_{8}}$ to 
$\Omega_5^{Spin \times_{} \mathbb Z_{8}}$,

we find:

$$X' \mod 2  =(a  \mod 2) (b  \mod 2)^2= Sq^2\big((a  \mod 2) (b  \mod 2)\big)$$ 
$$=(w_2(TM)+w_1(TM)^2)\big((a  \mod 2) (b  \mod 2)\big) =0,$$
the last equality is based on the Wu formula on a 5d spin manifold.

> My question is $$\frac{X'}{2}=\text{Postnikov square of } b?$$ 
>   where 
>   $$a \in H^1(B \mathbb Z_8,\mathbb Z_8),\quad  b \in H^2(B \mathbb Z_8, \mathbb Z_8).$$

---

PS. Recall, we find the Adams $\mathcal A$ module structure for $\Omega_5^{Spin  \times_{\mathbb Z_2} \mathbb Z_{4}} =\mathbb  Z_{16}$ and
$
\Omega_5^{Spin \times_{\mathbb Z_2} \mathbb Z_{8}}= \mathbb Z_{32} \times \mathbb Z_{2}$, are provided in my earlier post [Twisted spin bordism invariants in 5 dimensions](https://mathoverflow.net/q/323078/27004) .